# php 4 value checkbox wont show all in php

Tags: checkbox, php4

hello i have a little bit problem i am working on php4 and apache 1.1

```
<?php
$something="first second";
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="standard[]" value='.$something.'>first second<br>';
?>
```

Result:

```
first
```

and if

```
<?php
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="standard[]" value="first second">first second<br>';
    ?>
```

Result:

```
first second
```

i want my code is like the first one but the result is in second one, how? thanks

Comment: hello check the answer and respond back

Comment: wkwkk,,, thanks anyway...
i found the problem...
'.$something.' is replaced to "'.$something.'"
to all value of input
thanks

Comment: you didnt accept the ans yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do something like that

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="standard[]" value="'.$something.'">'.$something.'<br>';
```

one way to debugg such things is to check what is their output like `view on source` or `inspect elements`

[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) about `'` and `"`

Comment: are you sure you did like above ?

Comment: show me now your code and show me its output by inspect elements or view page source

Comment: wkwkk,,, thanks anyway... i found the problem... '.$something.' is replaced to "'.$something.'" to all value of input thanks

Comment: can you tell why u need name as standard[]?